# Self-referencing relationship in Entity Framework with child includes

Tags: linq, entity-framework, relationship

Is there any way of including child object within a self referencing relationship.  For example, I have an object like this:

```
class Activity
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public String Name {get;set;}

    public IList<Document> Documents {get;set;}
    public IList<Activity> ChildActivities {get;set;}
}
```

and I call it in linq like so:

```
from act in context.Activities.Include("Documents").Include("ChildActivities")
                      where act.Id == id
                      select act;
```

but the ChildActivities -> Documents object is always null, is there any way of including these as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "dotted paths" to include deeper levels of navigation properties. For your example you can write:

```
from act in context.Activities
    .Include("Documents")
    .Include("ChildActivities.Documents")
where act.Id == id
select act;
```

An explicit `Include("ChildActivities")` is not necessary here because EF will include all entities automatically that are on the path to the included final navigation property.

BTW: If you are using EF >= 4.1 you have a strongly typed version for `Include` available that takes a lambda expression as parameter:

```
using System.Data.Entity; // <- this namespace is required for the lambda-Include

//...

from act in context.Activities
    .Include(a => a.Documents)
    .Include(a => a.ChildActivities.Select(ca => ca.Documents))
where act.Id == id
select act;
```

Comment: I tried the first way already but for some reason that was still coming back as null, so I tried the lambda way and that worked, good to know about that way as well, cheers

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to take advantage of Entity Framework's [Lazy Loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456855(v=vs.100).aspx) features.

You would need to alter your object slightly by adding to `virtual` keyword to your navigation properties so they meet EF [requirements for creating POCO proxies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
public class Activity
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public String Name {get;set;}

    public virtual IList<Document> Documents {get;set;}
    public virtual IList<Activity> ChildActivities {get;set;}
}
```

You should now be able to access the `Documents` of your `ChildActivities` without having to explicitly load them (either via [Eager/Explicit loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456855(v=vs.100).aspx)).